# How to check if a condition in foreach function matched in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript function. 
I check a condition for every element in an array and if there is a match, I stop the loop.
For example:

```
var myarray = [5,6,7,8,9,10];
myarray.forEach(function(element){
  if(element == 8)
    break;
});

//myother functions here..
```

Everything seems okay so far. But after breaking the loop, my other functions continues to run.

If a match happens in foreach function, i don't want to continue to next functions, if nothing match it can continue.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your other functions are called outside the loop? The break only breaks out of the loop and doesn't continue to check the rest of the array elements.

Comment: Yes, my other functions are outside the loop. I want to stop them if a condition matches in loop.

Comment: If @Jameson 's answer wasn't the case post the full code

Comment: *"Everything seems okay so far. But after breaking the loop"* - The `break` statement doesn't exit a `.forEach()` loop, and the code shown would give an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you could use (version without functions)

```
var myarray = [5,6,7,8,9,10];
var found = false;
myarray.forEach(function(element){
  if(element == 8)
    found = true;
});

if (!found) {
  //myother functions here..
}
```

Or if you are just looking for a single element

```
if (myarray.indexOf(8) == -1) {
  //myother functions here..
}
```